# PHP - How to upload image in a multidimensional array loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, file-upload, phpmyadmin

**I am not able to upload image, I tried using the below code to display. But nothing gets displayed.**

PHP Code is as

```
$question_image = $allquestion["'ques_image'"];<br>
$imagetemp = $_FILES[$question_image]['name'];<br>
echo "IMAGE NAME".$imagetemp;
```

And Returned Array

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        ['ques_title'] => Question 1
        ['ques_image'] => galaxy_s7_black.png
        ['choice'] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Question 1 - First Choice
                        [1] => 127
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Question 1 - second Choice
                        [1] => 128
                    )
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        ['ques_title'] => Question 2
        ['ques_image'] => iphone7_rosegold.png
        ['choice'] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Question 2 - First Choice
                        [1] => 131
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Question 2 - second Choice
                        [1] => 132
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

How to upload image in a multidimensional array loop.

Comment: `ques_image` contains image name only of the image file?

Comment: add the value of  `print_r( $_FILES)` what it will return ?

Comment: @PrateikDarji name="quiz[1]['ques_image']" this is how I am submitting data.

Comment: @Narayan , it outputs empty array

Comment: @topper1309 if it will return empty then, check your form attribute have you added `enctype=multipart/form-data` ?

Comment: I guess array contains only image name instead of covering the image file you can use `print_r($_FILES)` as suggested by @Narayan

Comment: @Narayan- thank you, now the array ouputs the data but I am still not able to upload the image. I have updated the $_FILES output

Answer (score 0):

How did you print the array?

You must call the array arguments in step-by-step

for example :

```
echo $_FILES[1]['ques_image']
```

or

```
echo $_FILES[2]['ques_image']
```